# FIR filter design and implementation meaning

Tags: filters, convolution, finite-impulse-response

What is the output of the convolution meaning which is used in the FIR filter?

how can conclude the output of the FIR filter in the output according to the input $x[n]$?

Comment: Do you think you could clarify the question a little bit? I appreciate that certain things might not be clear to you and this is probably why you were motivated to post this question but could you perhaps provide an example, of what you mean by *"...output according to the input..."*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand how you are expressing your question in English, so please accept my attempt.

Discrete convolution is 
$$ y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n-k] h[k]
$$
where $y[n]$ is the output at time index $n$ and $h[k]$ is the impulse response.  The index $k$ ranges over $-\infty$ to $\infty$ if $h[n]$ is an infinite impulse response.

A causal convolution, i.e. the filter can only have output $y[n]$ for $x[n]$ ,$x[n-1]$ ,$x[n-2]$ $\dots$ $x[n-\infty]$ 
$$ y[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x[n-k] h[k]
$$
if $h[0]\ne 0$, $h[1]\ne 0$, $h[2] \ne 0$, $\dots$ $h[N-1]\ne 0$ , $h[N]=0$,  $h[N+1]=0$, $\dots$,  $h[\infty]=0$, is of finite length, it is a FIR filter and

> what is the output of the convolution meaning which is used in the FIR
>   filter ?

$$ y[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[n-k] h[k]
$$

> how can conclude the output of the FIR filter in the output according
>   to the input x[n]?

$y[n]$ depends on a finite sum of $x[n]$  .  A FIR filter also need not necessarily be causal, but it doesn't change that $y[n]$ only depends on a finite sum of $x[n]$

I don't understand how design has anything to do with your question.

Comment: i feel of no understanding the coefficient of the filter which is used to increase the ideal response of the filter and how it's effect on the output if it removed or added ,is the order of the filter increase the accuracy of magnitude or the amplitude?

Comment: @eng.muthana neither.

Comment: you don't need single answers, what you need is a good signals & systems textbook. You're at a uni , right? What book does your signal theory course recommend?